# print path of shortestpath C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl, dijkstra

I am new to STL based c++ usage. Can anyone help me how to proceed with the following code in printing "path of vertices" that yielded the shortestpath score for each destination vertex along with the shortestpath value.

Please find the working code link taken from geeksforgeeks platform.

http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/index.php
// Program to find Dijkstra's shortest path using STL set

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
# define INF 0x3f3f3f3f

// This class represents a directed graph using 
// adjacency list representation
class Graph
{
    int V; // No. of vertices

    // In a weighted graph, we need to store vertex 
    // and weight pair for every edge
    list< pair<int, int> > *adj;

public:
    Graph(int V); // Constructor

    // function to add an edge to graph
    void addEdge(int u, int v, int w);

    // prints shortest path from s
    void shortestPath(int s);
};

// Allocates memory for adjacency list
Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list< pair<int, int> >[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v, int w)
{
    adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v, w));
    adj[v].push_back(make_pair(u, w));
}

// Prints shortest paths from src to all other vertices
void Graph::shortestPath(int src)
{
    // Create a set to store vertices that are being
    // prerocessed
    set< pair<int, int> > setds;

    // Create a vector for distances and initialize all
    // distances as infinite (INF)
    vector<int> dist(V, INF);

    // Insert source itself in Set and initialize its
    // distance as 0.
    setds.insert(make_pair(0, src));
    dist[src] = 0;

    /* Looping till all shortest distance are finalized
    then setds will become empty */
    while (!setds.empty())
    {
        // The first vertex in Set is the minimum distance
        // vertex, extract it from set.
        pair<int, int> tmp = *(setds.begin());
        setds.erase(setds.begin());

        // vertex label is stored in second of pair (it
        // has to be done this way to keep the vertices
        // sorted distance (distance must be first item
        // in pair)
        int u = tmp.second;

        // 'i' is used to get all adjacent vertices of a vertex
        list< pair<int, int> >::iterator i;
        for (i = adj[u].begin(); i != adj[u].end(); ++i)
        {
            // Get vertex label and weight of current adjacent
            // of u.
            int v = (*i).first;
            int weight = (*i).second;

            // If there is shorter path to v through u.
            if (dist[v] > dist[u] + weight)
            {
                /* If distance of v is not INF then it must be in
                    our set, so removing it and inserting again
                    with updated less distance. 
                    Note : We extract only those vertices from Set
                    for which distance is finalized. So for them, 
                    we would never reach here. */
                if (dist[v] != INF)
                    setds.erase(setds.find(make_pair(dist[v], v)));

                // Updating distance of v
                dist[v] = dist[u] + weight;
                setds.insert(make_pair(dist[v], v));
            }
        }
    }

    // Print shortest distances stored in dist[]
    printf("Vertex Distance from Source\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i)
        printf("%d \t\t %d\n", i, dist[i]);
}

// Driver program to test methods of graph class
int main()
{
    // create the graph given in above fugure
    int V = 9;
    Graph g(V);

    // making above shown graph
    g.addEdge(0, 1, 4);
    g.addEdge(0, 7, 8);
    g.addEdge(1, 2, 8);
    g.addEdge(1, 7, 11);
    g.addEdge(2, 3, 7);
    g.addEdge(2, 8, 2);
    g.addEdge(2, 5, 4);
    g.addEdge(3, 4, 9);
    g.addEdge(3, 5, 14);
    g.addEdge(4, 5, 10);
    g.addEdge(5, 6, 2);
    g.addEdge(6, 7, 1);
    g.addEdge(6, 8, 6);
    g.addEdge(7, 8, 7);

    g.shortestPath(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You link only links to the online IDE, not to specific code. Just post the code into the question, questions are supposed to be answerable without clicking on links.

Comment: ohh Sorry ! Yeah I will post here ..Thanks

Comment: 1) The link that you have provided takes you to an empty example. 2) Do not post links, instead post a [minimal, verifiable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 3) Please clearly state what is the output you expect and what errors or problems you are finding.

Comment: Here is the working code. How can I save the list of vertices that are contributing to the shortestpath for each destination vertex ?

Comment: Don't include<bits/stdc++.h>, it's a private non standard header not meant for inclusion.

Comment: One way: in `dist`, store not only the shortest distance, but also the vertex via which that distance was achieved. Whenever you update the distance under `dist[v] > dist[u] + weight` condition, store the new (shorter) distance and also vertex `u` under `dist[v]`. This way, you could trace those links back to `src`.